# Create JavaRDD from list in Spark 2.0

Tags: spark-java

The usual way of creating a JavaRDD from a list is to use `JavaSparkContext.parallelize(List)`

However, in Spark 2.0 `SparkSession` is used as entry point and I don't know how to create a JavaRDD from a List

Answer (score 5):

I had the same Problem. What I did so far:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Any", "List", "with", "Strings");
Dataset<String> listDS = sparkSession.createDataset(list, Encoders.STRING()); 
JavaRDD<String> javaRDDString = listDS.toJavaRDD();
```

One reason for me to do this is for example that i want to use `flatMap` which works fine with `JavaRDD<String>` but not with `Dataset<String>`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: Spark-shell (Spark 2.0)

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
val jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc)
val javaRDD:java.util.List[Int]= java.util.Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
jsc.parallelize(javaRDD)
```

[Spark Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#tab_java_3)